# Akka - when should I use the Bootable class

Tags: scala, akka

In Akka, I can initialize an actor system from the main(), like this:

```
object HostManagerApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("Foo", ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("Bar"))
  }
}
```

Alternatively, I can do the same from a class that extends `Bootable`. As mentioned in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/kernel/Bootable.html), this also allows me to start the app from the command line. What's the difference between the two approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a way to make your code more modular. Using Bootable you can have different independent  actor systems in different scala classes all bootstrapping independently, instead of putting them all in one main class.

Answer (score 1):

Bootable is used with the Akka Microkernel, and if you package your Akka application as a Bootable then you can run multiple applications within the same ActorSystem.

Comment: if you look at the code of the microkernel and examples, the `Bootable` has to create its own `ActorSystem`, so every applications will launch separate actor systems.

Answer (score 0):

`Akka Microkernel` with `Bootable` is deprecated since Akka 2.4 - please read [migration guide that explains this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/project/migration-guide-2.3.x-2.4.x.html#Microkernel_is_Deprecated) further.